# Extract img tag from a web page with DOMdocument and getElementByTagName functions

Tags: php, html, domdocument, getelementsbytagname

I've to extract the source code from a web page of my WP site. I've to extrapolate every  tag. The page is the product details and I've to modified the code of woocommerceprintproduct plugin. 
I added in the plugin code the following code:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTMLFile("http://www.pecso.it/prodotto/741drinkflex-piatto-nondiv/");
var_dump($dom); 
$imgTags = $dom->getElementsByTagName("img");
var_dump($imgTags);
```

Printing `$imgTags` I obtain the following value:
`object(DOMNodeList)#20572 (1) { ["length"]=> int(34) }`

Now, can I extract every `<img>` tag?

Comment: imgTag is object what are you trying to get ???

Comment: I try to get img tag from the web page..

Comment: You have got that ..  do you want src???

Comment: I've to insert into a PDF document the img tag (with every its attribute) with a specific class..

Answer (score 0):

```
    $images_links = [];$i=0;
    $img_tags = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
    if (!is_null($img_tags)) {
       foreach ($img_tags as $img_tag) {
           if ($img_tag->hasAttribute('src')) {
               $src_value = $img_tag->getAttribute('src');
               $images_links[$i] = $src_value;
               $i++;
            }
       }
   }
```

This way you can get attribute and so on

Comment: thank's but $images_links remains empty.. I think that the problem is the value returned from $dom->loadHTMLFile('...') because to print it I don't find src that I find inspecting the page..